# Elasticsearch-py Bulk Percolate Functionality

Tags: elasticsearch-py, elasticsearch-percolate

Trying to get the bulk percolate functionality to work for Elasticsearch-py (i.e. mpercolate), but haven't been able to find an example online. I'm able to use the percolate function, so I can get this to work:

```
doc = {'doc' : {'field1' : 'this is a value', 'field2' : 'this is another value'}}
res = es.percolate(index = 'my_index', doc_type = 'my_doc_type', body = doc)
```

The documentation I've read so far seems to imply that if I want to do a bulk submission, I need to send header and body as strings, separated by a newline. Thus I've tried:

```
head = {'percolate' : {'index' : 'my_index', 'type' : 'my_doc_type'}}    
doc = {'doc' : {'field1' : 'this is a value', 'field2' : 'this is another value'}}
doc2 = {'doc' : {'field1' : 'values and values', 'field2' : 'billions of values'}}

query_list = [head, doc, head, doc2]
my_body = '\n'.join([str(qry) for qry in query_list])

res = es.mpercolate(body = my_body)
```

which gives me a generic "elasticsearch.exceptions.TransportError". Anyone have a working example I can adapt?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to serialize the data yourself, just pass in the `query_list` as body and it should do the right thing